# Smooth Scrolling is not working in viewpage indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpage

I am working on **circular view page indicator**(Looping).Based on the stackoverflow solution i implemented Circularviewpager class and it was working fine.The Issue which i am facing here is i have four images in array namely A,B,C,D. If i swipe left from D it moves to A  image **without any animation or smooth scrolling like swiping image from A to B image**.I tried may methods to acheive this nothing is working out and i attached my code below suggest me some solution to acheive this.

```
public class HomeScreen extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mPager;
private CirclePageIndicator mIndicator;
private PromotionalAdapter mAdapter;
private static int count = 0;
private static Context ctx;
protected int orientation;
protected int width = 0;
protected int height = 0;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
int currentPosition = 0;
int backPosition = 0;
//
private int mCurrentPos;
private int mScrollState;
LinearLayout itemContainer;
List<ImageView> itemImage;
TextView currentText;
private int previousState, currentState;
int currentPage;

public static final void createPromotionalPager(HomeScreen home,
                                                TypedArray drawables) {

    home.mAdapter = new PromotionalAdapter(
            home.getSupportFragmentManager(), drawables);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ctx = this;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    initialUISetup();


}
private void screenDisplay() {
    TypedArray drawables = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.launchscreen_images);
    createPromotionalPager(this, drawables);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new CircularViewPageHandler(mPager));
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    int leftRightSpace = (int) (width * 0.0153);
    int topBottomSpace = (int) (height * 0.0089);
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        leftRightSpace = (int) (height * 0.0153);
        topBottomSpace = (int) (width * 0.0089);
    }
    mIndicator.setSnap(true);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

}
public static class PromotionalFragment extends Fragment {
    private Drawable mDrawable;

    public static PromotionalFragment newInstance(Drawable drawable) {
        PromotionalFragment fragment = new PromotionalFragment();
        fragment.setDrawable(drawable);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.promotional_fragment, container,
                false);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.promotional_picture);
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);

        return v;
    }

    public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mDrawable = drawable;
    }

}

public static class     PromotionalAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final TypedArray mPictures;
    public static int LOOPS_COUNT = 2;

    public PromotionalAdapter(FragmentManager fm, TypedArray drawables) {
        super(fm);
        mPictures = drawables;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        try {
            return PromotionalFragment.newInstance(mPictures
                    .getDrawable(arg0));


        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        count = mPictures.length();
        return mPictures.length();


    }

}


public void initialUISetup() {


    setContentView(R.layout.launchscreen_layout);

    screenDisplay();

}
}
}
```

//CircularViewPageHandler.java

```
public class CircularViewPageHandler implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
private ViewPager   mViewPager;
private int         mCurrentPosition;
private int         mScrollState;
int mInitialPage=0;
public CircularViewPageHandler(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    mViewPager = viewPager;
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
    mCurrentPosition = position;

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

    handleScrollState(state);
    mScrollState = state;
}

private void handleScrollState(final int state) {
    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        setNextItemIfNeeded();
    }
}

private void setNextItemIfNeeded() {
    if (!isScrollStateSettling()) {
        handleSetNextItem();
    }
}

private boolean isScrollStateSettling() {
    return mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING;

}

private void handleSetNextItem() {
    final int lastPosition = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
    if(mCurrentPosition == 0) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(lastPosition, false);


    } else if(mCurrentPosition == lastPosition) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);

    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
    Log.e("position",""+position);

}
}
```